# Need help with update to latest Git using Terminal

Tags: terminal, homebrew, path, git

I was trying to update to the latest Git version in my Terminal. I've no clue what I did and all I remember was that I removed the previous installed Git I think because when i run the following commands:

```
which git => /usr/local/bin/git
git --version => -bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory
brew install git => Warning: git-2.2.1 already installed
brew doctor => Your system is ready to brew.
brew link git => Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.2.1
$PATH => "/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:‌​/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

My question is what should i do next so that I can use Git ?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that git's location is still cached in `/usr/bin` (the default location). To check this, type:

```
type git
```

The result will likely be:

```
git is hashed (/usr/bin/git)
```

To fix this, you can simply log out & back in, or clear the hash for git with the following:

```
hash -d git
```

Now, running git should work properly.

Comment: I spent literally half an hour working on this, nowhere else was the hashing mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: One of the best answers, working fine with Mac OS.